# Calculate AVG interval in powerBI

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

For a project I have to calculate the AVG interval of different types of items.

Example data

```
|source|name|type|date      |time    |
|ABC   |AP1 |AP  |02/01/2020|11:45:23|
|ABC   |AP1 |AP  |02/01/2020|12:50:26|
|ABC   |AP1 |AP  |02/01/2020|14:15:23|
|ABC   |AP2 |PI  |02/01/2020|15:21:12|
|ABC   |AP2 |PI  |02/01/2020|16:22:12|
|ABC   |AP2 |OK  |02/01/2020|16:04:21|
```

What I need to do is to calculate the avg interval of the past 6 months per source, name , type combination.

I have tried multiple different outcomes in SQL but so far it only gives me the latest time it was updated and most solutions online haven't been able to help me. I am hoping someone has an idea or a tip so I can continue.

Code so far

```
select Source, name, Type, count(time)
from myTable
where time>= DATEADD(month, -6, getdate())
group by Source, name, Type,
```

**Edit**

The expected result should show the avg interval so something like

```
|source|name|type|date      |time    |avg interval|
|ABC   |AP1 |AP  |02/01/2020|11:45:23|00:45:00    |
|ABC   |AP1 |AP  |02/01/2020|12:50:26|00:45:00    |
|ABC   |AP1 |AP  |02/01/2020|14:15:23|00:45:00    |
|ABC   |AP2 |PI  |02/01/2020|15:21:12|01:01:00    |
|ABC   |AP2 |PI  |02/01/2020|16:22:12|01:01:00    |
|ABC   |AP2 |OK  |02/01/2020|16:04:21|24:00:00    |
```

Comment: Sample table data is great, but you should also specify the expected result.

Comment: Yes, please give us the table with the results you expect to get from the above provied dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what results you want.  But the following only uses data from the last six months and calculates the average spaces where there is more than one row:

```
select Source, name, Type,
       datediff(second, min(time), max(time)) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0)
from myTable
where time>= DATEADD(month, -6, getdate())
group by Source, name, Type;
```

Note:  This does not include any time after the most recent row for each source.